# Wordpress get_posts will accept numbers but not an identical variable

Tags: php, variables

The following is fully functional in wordpress using the get_posts function

```
$args = array( 'post__in' => array(63,57,34,) );
```

This on the other hand does not:

```
$ids = 63,57,34,;
    $args = array( 'post__in' => array($ids) );
```

Since we generate the variable by another equation we need to use the second one, but it will only give us the first result not all 3. Why?

**UPDATE**

the `$ids` is generated from a foreach looking for certain criteria.

```
if($final != false){ 

            $ids .= $result->ID . ',' ;

         }
```

The full code is as such.

```
$proto = $_GET['p'];
$terms = $_GET['s'];

if($proto == 'inline') {

    $search = get_posts('post_type=post&post_status=publish');

    foreach($search as $result) {

        $title = get_the_title($result);

        $tags = wp_get_post_tags( $result->ID);

        foreach($tags as $tag){ $tago[$result->ID].= $tag->name.',';}

        $full = $title . ' ' . $tago[$result->ID];

        $final = strpos($full,$terms);


        if($final != false){ 

            $ids .= $result->ID . ',' ;

         }

    }

    echo $ids;
    $args = array( 'post__in' => array($ids) );

    $srs = get_posts($args);

    foreach($srs as $sr) { echo $sr->post_title;

     }


}
```

Comment: The latter will cause a syntax error. Can you show the original code?

Comment: @Pekka I've added the full equation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing two different things as your `post__in` value.  The first is an array of integers.  The second is an array containing a single string.  You can see the difference with:

```
$working = array(63,57,34,);
print_r($working);

$not_working = array('63,57,34,');
print_r($not_working);
```

I suspect WordPress is using `intval()` or similar on the members of the array to sanitize its input, which is why you're only getting the first element.

I'd suggest declaring `$ids` as an array before your loop:

```
$ids = array();
```

and appending the values with:

```
$ids[] = $result->ID;
```

in your loop.  Then `$args` can be set with:

```
$args = array( 'post__in' => $ids );
```

Comment: I have an additional problem if you could help. Added to the question

Comment: @RobinKnight: Don't do that. Write a new question.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal I tried to but it won't let me, It says I have reached my limit. Perhaps you could post it for me

Comment: @RobinKnight: Post it tomorrow. The limit is there to encourage you not to use Stack Overflow as a first resort; try to learn from that rather than attempting to hack around it!